# Chaining Selects with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am brand new, just experimenting, with AngularJS framework. So I am not sure the approach I have taken is the best/right way.

I'm trying to create a 3 level chained ajax filled select boxes, and it is kind of working, except for a couple of issues.

My actual code uses ajax which is in a factory, but for the sake of the fiddle I just have a controller returning results from an array.

**Demo (using arrays, not ajax):** http://jsfiddle.net/xxwe1zu8/1/

**Issues:**

1. 2nd and 3rd level selects don't have a "selected" attribute - ie the one you select doesn't get highlighted.
2. Ideally I would like the top level categories to be dynamically filled on page load via ajax (or in this example by array) using the same angular function (eg: getSubcategories = function(0, 0) {) rather than hardcoded. Top level categories have a parent of 0.
3. **Bonus**: Can the 3rd select box only be shown/visible if there is a sub sub category returned after selecting the sub category? In reality, most sub categories won't have sub sub categories.

   ```
   var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp',[]);
   myAppModule.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope) {
   var self = this;

   self.subCategories = [];
   self.getSubcategories = function(parent, level) {

       theCategories = [];

           angular.forEach(sub_category[parent], function(idx, val) {
                theCategories.push({id: val, name: idx});
           });


       self.subCategories[level] = theCategories;
   }       
   });
   ```

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason to have non-continuous indices for array of categories?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to restructure data in an array of objects and get rid of indicies which are seemingly of no use here.

```
var transport = [
    {
        name: "Cars",
        models: [
            {
                name: "Hatchback",
                variations: ["4 door", "5 door"]
            },
            {
                name: "Sedan",
                variations: ["4 door", "5 door"]
            },
            {
                name: "SUV",
                variations: ["Medium", "Large"]
            }
        ]
    },
 ...
```

This allows to make clearer code in template. I am not ControllerAs syntax here since `$scope` is injected in any way. And it is a better approach if you just start learning AngularJS

```
    <select 
         ng-model="selectedType" 
         ng-options="t.name for t in transport"
         ng-change = "selectedModel=null;selectedVariation=null">
         <option value="">Select type</option>
    </select>

    <select 
         ng-model="selectedModel" 
         ng-options="model.name for model in selectedType.models"
         ng-change="selectedVariation=null" 
         ng-show="selectedType.models">
        <option value="">Select model</option>
    </select>

    <span ng-show="loading">Loading...</span>
    <select 
         ng-model="selectedVariation" 
         ng-options="variation for variation in variations"
         ng-show="variations && !loading">
        <option value="">Select variation</option>
    </select>
```

`selectedType`, `selectedModel` and `selectedVariation` are implicitly defined in `$scope` by `ng-model` of each select. There is even no mention of them in controller currently. At the same time this properties are used in `ng-show` to hide `select` tags which are not relevant in current selection.
The last `select` (sub subcategory) demonstrates a way to fetch data asynchronously. Let's imagine you don't have a complete tree of data at once and fetch variations from server on model selection. You would place a watch in controller for `selectedModel` and if it was selected (not emptied) you would launch a request for data and update variations on response

```
$scope.$watch('selectedModel', function(model){
    if(model){
        $scope.loading = true;
        //setTimeout imitates an ajax request
        setTimeout(function(){
            $scope.variations = model.variations;
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.$apply();
        }, 1000);
    }
})
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/xxwe1zu8/3/)

Comment: You can add it as `id` property of the object which is a more common way in javascript. See updated answer for asynchronous loading of data tree

Comment: Thanks, I kind of understand the way you have done it, but not sure how to go from a flat DB table (which already exists and that I need to use)  with the specs = [id, name, parent_id] via ajax to your "var transport" way.

Comment: .....The way I am trying to do it uses the id from the DB table as the value in the select's "<option value=...", which we then use onclick to find the children categories via ajax.

Comment: Well in any case you know how to parse flat schema you have into a tree. The way `variations` are displayed kind of gives the clue how you do this. You will need to obtain the `id` of a selected model and query server for all variations of this model